# Flutter: How to pass over a function with parameters

Tags: flutter

What i want to do is this: I have a list of 'folder' objects and i want to pass them over to my stateless class ('FolderTile.dart'). In there i have a function that on press changes the bool 'is locked' and the icon, 'icon' that is shown on screen. My problem is with passing the 'unlockingLock' function over to the stateless widget
I have tried to do it multiple ways but none of them worked. Some of them are just below.

I would really appreciate if someone would be kind enough to at least guide me in the right direction. Just got into flutter after a bit of c++ background and this seems to be the first roadblock that i encounter.

```
//attempts:
unlockingLock: unlockingLock(folders[index].isLocked, folders[index].icon) 
//-> gives me an error that i am trying to call the function while the class is being built


unlockingLock: unlockingLock() // -> unable to check the parameters in the first place
```

folder_list.dart

```
class Folder {
  final String folderName;
  bool isLocked;
  int numberOfElements;
  Icon icon;
  Folder({this.folderName, this.isLocked = false, this.numberOfElements = 0, this.icon = const Icon(Icons.lock_outline)});

}

class FoldersList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FoldersListState createState() => _FoldersListState();

}

class _FoldersListState extends State<FoldersList> {

  dynamic unlockingLock(index){
    Folder instance = folders[index];

    if (instance.isLocked == false) {
        print('now locked');
        instance.isLocked = true;
        instance.icon = Icon(Icons.lock_outline);
      } else {
        print('now unlocked');
        instance.isLocked = false;
        instance.icon = Icon(Icons.lock_open);
      }
  }

  List<Folder> folders = [
    Folder(folderName: 'Folder01', isLocked: true, numberOfElements: 5,),
    Folder(folderName: 'Folder02', isLocked: false, numberOfElements: 0,),
  ];

  void checkFunction()
  {
    for(int i =0; i<folders.length;i++)
      {
          if (folders[i].isLocked == false) {
        folders[i].icon =  Icon(Icons.lock_open);
        }
        else{
           folders[i].icon =  Icon(Icons.lock_outline);
        }
      }
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    checkFunction();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: folders.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return FolderTile(
          folderName: folders[index].folderName,
          isLocked: folders[index].isLocked,
          numberOfElements: folders[index].numberOfElements,
          icon: folders[index].icon,
          index: index,
          unlockingLock: unlockingLock(index),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

FolderTile.dart

```
class FolderTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final int numberOfElements ;
  final String folderName ;
  final bool isLocked ;
  final Icon icon;
  final Function unlockingLock;
  final int index;
  final Color folderColor = Colors.green.shade200;

  FolderTile({this.folderName, this.numberOfElements, this.isLocked, this.icon, this.index, this.unlockingLock});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: folderColor,
      child: ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, InsideFolder.id);
        },
        title: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(numberOfElements.toString()),
            GestureDetector(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 30.0,
              ),
              onTap: () {
                print('open sub folders'); //drop down menu
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        trailing: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[

            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => unlockingLock(index),       //FUNCTION CALLED HERE
              child: icon,
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 4.0),
            Text('$numberOfElements elements'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I would also like to know why i can not pass a void function over and have to set it up as 'dynamic'

Comment: `unlockingLock: unlockingLock` - when you use: `unlockingLock: unlockingLock()` you are actually passing the value returned by `unlockingLock` method

Comment: fixed that. i got it working but it seems that still in the 'FolderTile' when i call onTap: () => unlockingLock, it doesn't actually gets called. Any idea why? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: because inside `FolderTile` you have to **call** it, like: `onTap: () => unlockingLock(someIndex)`

Comment: a better approach for your case, making the FiliTile.dart a statefull widget, lt it do its job and when it gets updated it calls a function in the parnet, like onUpdate,

Comment: @pskink I did that but the widgets are not updating. I can definitely see the print statements staying the same every time i press the button. have i not implemented the setState correctly?